# Crystal Reports - Sub report with Cross Tab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal Report with a sub report. All that the sub report has on it is a Cross Tab.

The Sub Report on it's own spans to the second page which is OK (although I'd like to know how to repeat the left hand column on the second page but that is another question).

However, when it is embedded in the main report the second page of the Cross Tab does not show - just the first page does

How can I get all pages of the sub report to show when fired from the main report?

Comment: Have you checked the linking from main report to sub report? May be data is getting filtered when you linked.

Comment: Yes, linking is correct